# JSON wrapped in NULL?

Tags: python, json

I'm using the API of an affiliate network (Sovrn), expecting to retrieve a product's specification using the URL.

As per their documentation, I use:

```
url = 'URL-goes-here'

headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "authorization": "VERY-HARD-TO-GUESS"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

The code is working, the response I get is `200`, the header contains the magical `content-type     application/json` line

when I do

```
print(response.text)
```

I get

```
NULL({"merchantName":"Overstock","canonicalUrl":"URL goes here","title":"product name",...});
```

I tested for response type of `response.text`, it's `<class 'str'>` as expected. But when I try to process the response as json:

```
product_details = json.load(response.text)
```

I get an error message:

```
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: [Errno Expecting value]
```

I'm new to JSON, but I assume the error is due to the outer NULL that the (seemingly valid) data is wrapped in.

After spending a few hours searching for a solution, it seems that I must be missing something obvious, but not sure what.

Any pointers would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Is this an officially sanctioned API, or are you using someone's private API? If the latter, then yeah, it's probably wrapped in some nonsense explicitly to deter people like you. Or you've accidentally picked the *JSONP* API instead.

Comment: Does *response.json()* give you anything sensible?

Comment: Looking at Sovrn's documentation, you probably are indeed hitting a JSON-P API. Does your real code say `callback='NULL'` or anything like it?

Comment: @deceze: The "Try it" button on their documentation shows no JSONP wrapping with an empty "callback" field, and "NULL(...)" if I put `NULL` for `callback`. Some of the pages have `NULL` pre-populated in the `callback` field, and I think the questioner may have assumed they were actually supposed to use that value, but taking it out seems to produce a non-JSONP response.

Comment: To answer all questions, this is the official Sovrn API, and no reference is made to JSONP whatsoever. This is the Python API using JSON (the alternative solution is XML - I haven't tested that one).

Thanks for all your support, @tdelaney's solution below solved the issue

Comment: There's a `callback` parameter [documented](https://i.imgur.com/SKZJzs5.png) as "JSON-P callback method name" on most of their API endpoints that produces the behavior you're seeing if you pass `'NULL'` for that parameter.

Comment: fair point, I haven't spotted that one... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's clearly a bug in the API. Assuming it will be fixed after you complain, you could add a hack to your code

```
def sovrn_json_load_hack(json_text):
    """sovrn is returning invalid json as of (revision here)."""
    if not json_text.startswith ("NULL("):
        return json.loads(json_text)
    else:
        return json.loads(json_text[5:-2])
```

Comment: This did the trick, thank you very much!

I was hesitant to open a ticket with Sovrn, assuming it was my mistake, but now I will flag this to them.

It's interesting no one ran into this before (or at least I couldn't trace it if someone did).

Thanks, anyway, happy new year!

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore `NULL(` at the beginning and `);` at the end by using string slicing:

```
product_details = json.loads(response.text[5:-2])
```

Additionally, you should be using [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) as the content is a string.